# Can you change VS Win Forms designer code generation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, code-generation, windows-forms-designer

We implemented new coding standards, which call for our private members to have a leading underscore. Like so:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label _label;
```

Unfortunately VS will put out the default below when you drag a new label onto your form:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
```

Is there a way to change the default to:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label _label1;
```

This pertains to all controls, not just labels, and yes they are to be used from code.

Cheers,

Plamen

Comment: Surely you'll be changing the name from the default anyway...

Comment: Yeah but the way we have it, it's supposed to be _labelContactName, so we have to append to the end of the name. Going to the beginning to add the underscore, while not a huge deal, seems to be a waste. Also, people don't do it consistently, and I figure that would improve if the default had an underscore.

Comment: The label will be access from code. I guess at this point, I'm defending the question on improved consistency grounds only :).

Comment: The tool to enforce coding coventions is FxCop and not the designer in my opinion. You can also treat warning as errors to make FxCop warning fail the build in case developers are not following the conventions.

Comment: Is that only for labels or for all controls? If only for labels, I'd say that I often don't end up accessing them from my code and otherwise, if for all controls, I might very well have have a DateTimePicker for the start of something, would that end up being called _dateTimePickerStart? If so, seems a bit extreme with only 25% of the name being the actual name.

Comment: Agreed, the standards were implemented against my better judgement, I just wanna make sure that we're not swimming against the current. Yes, this pertains to all controls, DateTimePickers included.

Comment: Agree with Ikaso.  Use FxCop and StyleCop, or convince your company to shell out some money for ReSharper.

Comment: The joy of silly standards... 
I would then agree with Ikaso that you might want to look at FxCop rules.

Comment: Do you mind having to add a component to the form to enable the name changes?

Comment: +1 for good questions.It might be a good enhancement input for VS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond creating your own VS Add-In that watches for generated code and re-names it automatically, there is no way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I believe automatic generated code should be excluded to any coding guidelines and so on. It is safe to ignore them in most scenarios, unless the generator has a bug.

Please debate with whoever wrote that coding guidelines and ask him.her to exclude generated code.

Comment: I agree. If you try taming auto-generated code, you'll never get anything productive done. It may be "just" the WinForms Designer code today, but tomorrow you might have to deal with WCF's clients, Entity Framework mapping and maybe even monsters like what ANTLR generates. Lex is right, auto-generated code must be excluded from these kinds of requirements.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question but I have been working with custom designers lately and I have a solution for what you want. Add this class to you project:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    [Designer(typeof(BaseFormDesigner), typeof(IRootDesigner))]
    public class BaseForm : Form
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
        }
    }

    public class BaseFormDesigner : DocumentDesigner
    {
        public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
        {
            base.Initialize(component);
            var service = GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService)) as IComponentChangeService;
            service.ComponentAdded += service_ComponentAdded;
        }

        private void service_ComponentAdded(object sender, ComponentEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Component is Control && !(e.Component is Form)) {
                var control = (Control)e.Component;
                if (!control.Name.StartsWith("_")) {
                    var service = GetService(typeof(IComponentChangeService)) as IComponentChangeService;
                    PropertyDescriptor desc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(control)["Name"];
                    service.OnComponentChanging(e.Component, desc);
                    string oldValue = control.Name;
                    string newValue = "_" + oldValue;
                    desc.SetValue(control, newValue);
                    service.OnComponentChanged(e.Component, desc, oldValue, newValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then change your base form class from Form to BaseForm:

```
using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Close any form designers before recompiling your project and then reopen it and try adding a control, its name will start with underscore.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be unsatisfactory, but it's the best I can offer.

I don't think you can get the Visual Studio Designer to automatically add the underscore. However, what you can do is make the process of adding the underscore less painful. Just create your objects without the underscore first; then, use the Refactor feature to rename them. Just place your cursor on the name of the field (`label1`, in your case) and press F2 (or right-click ⇒ Refactor ⇒ Rename). This works no matter where in the code you are, all you need is a mention of `label1`. Since you'll probably be writing code that uses your controls, you'll probably be referencing the fields anyway. You can also press F12 to get straight to the declarations where you effectively get a full list of all your controls; you can easily use F2 to rename lots of them there in one go.

Incidentally, I also use F2 to rename most of the auto-generated event handler names. For example, I hate to see method names like `btnZoomIn_Click()`. I prefer to call the method `zoomIn()` because that is what it does. Instead of `Mainform_KeyPress()` I might call it `processKeyPress()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Timwi, I am aware of the refactoring capabilities of VS. Changing the name at design-time is a lot faster then doing it from code, I suspect it is optimized. Doing it from code compiles all your assemblies even for privates for whatever reason. I am looking for something I can set and forget, and would not require constant maintenance/human work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the GenerateMember to false.
This doesn't resolve your problem, but avoid for wrong naming, when you dont to work with control manually.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper can enforce naming conventions.  Then it's just a matter of opening the .designer file and hitting alt+enter, enter a few times.

Answer (score 0):

As BlueRaja said, you could use Resharper. You could then use its Code Cleanup (Ctrl-E, C), however this doesn't work on generated files, so you'll have to temporarily rename it. I'm not at work, so I can't check if there is an option to enable the option for generated files somewhere.

Note that you'll have to rerun this every time the file is regenerated.